# Sci-kit learn pairwise_distances is imprecise?

Tags: scikit-learn, precision

The scikit-learn function pairwise_distances provides the distance matrix from an array X.
However for some inputs the results seems not to be precise.

Example:

```
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import pairwise_distances
X = [[-0.903858372568, -0.5521578], [-0.903858372568, -0.55215782]]
print pairwise_distances(X)
```

Gives the following output:

```
[[ 0.  0.]
[ 0.  0.]]
```

Although there is a distance of 0.00000002.

2nd Example:

```
X = [[-0.903858372568, -0.5521578], [-0.903858372568, -0.552157821]]
```

gives

```
[[  0.00000000e+00   2.10734243e-08]
[  2.10734243e-08   0.00000000e+00]]
```

Here there is a distance but is only correct up to the first digit.

For my application it is undesirable if the output can be zero although there is a distance.
Is there a good way to increase the precision?

Comment: The pairwise distance functions in sklearn are optimized for speed. They decompose the euclidean distances into two norms and a matrix product and the result is not stable wrt numerical errors.

Comment: If your application relies on differences of `2e-7` you should seriously consider rescaling your equations/data ...

Comment: See also [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/2914)

Comment: See [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/11711)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't dig on why scikit-learn gives such unprecise result, but it seems scipy gives better precision. Try this:

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist, squareform
squareform(pdist(X))
```

For example,

```
X = [[-0.903858372568, -0.5521578], [-0.903858372568, -0.552157821]]
```

gives

```
array([[  0.00000000e+00,   2.10000000e-08],
       [  2.10000000e-08,   0.00000000e+00]])
```